# Access POST string from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I use `JQuery.ajax` to send a JavaScript object to a `PHP` script per `POST`. `JQuery` sends it in a way that makes it easily accessable from PHP:

JavaScript:

```
var request = $.ajax({
    url: server,
    dataType: 'text',
    timeout: timeout,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {key:"value"}
});
```

PHP:

```
$_POST["key"]
```

When I send a simple string with $.ajax instead of a JS object, how can I access it in PHP? E.g. when simply sending "data", `count($_POST)` returns 0.

```
var request = $.ajax({
    url: server,
    dataType: 'text',
    timeout: timeout,
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "text/plain",
    data: "data"
});
```

Do I have to use `file_get_contents('php://input')` or is there another way?

Comment: Why you can't send the string using the object?

Comment: `when simply sending "data"` You mean sending empty data? If yes, then obviously `count($_POST)` will return 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I send a simple string with $.ajax instead of a JS object, how can I access it in PHP?
>
> Do I have to use `file_get_contents('php://input')`

Yes. If you don't encode the data in a format that PHP can decode automatically, then you have to access the raw data like that.

Remember to set the `content-type` of the **request** to `text/plain` when you do that.

Comment: I disagree, valid data sent via any method to PHP can be accessed via $_POST (or $_GET depending upon the method).  The php://input allows you to access all data sent in it's raw form.

Comment: @PeteAUK — What? Nonsense. `$_POST` only gets populated when the data is sent using one of the two content-types supported by HTML 4 forms.

Comment: @PeteAUK Do you know how to access a single string in the $_POST variable?

Comment: @telandor — You can't. His solution is "Don't send simple strings".

Comment: Is `file_get_contents` a common solution or would it be better to convert the string into a JS object before sending it?

Comment: `file_get_contents` is the standard solution for getting data that isn't formatted in one of the two HTML 4 form encodings.

Comment: Do you mean the enctype attribute (there are three possible values)? If not, could you post a link to a description of the HTML4 form encodings?

Comment: [Two values are mentioned in the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-enctype) as far as I can see. HTML 5 introduces `text/plain` and then tells people not to use it.

Comment: I don't see why this has got into an argument.  PHP expects key/value pairs to be sent in order to access it via a $_POST, this is what I mean by "valid" data.  php://input is valid and I've used it in special cases, but they are less common than when I use $_POST.

Comment: @PeteAUK — Less common, perhaps, but it is the only way to get the data in the form the OP is sending it, and they are asking about how to get the data when they send it in that form.

Answer (score -1):

Your data should be valid, a string on its own isn't valid.  Instead try:

```
var request = $.ajax({
   url: server,
   dataType: 'text',
   timeout: timeout,
   type: 'POST',
   contentType: "text/plain",
   data: {data: "mysimplestring"}
```

});

and access it with

```
$_POST['data'];
```

Comment: `"data"` is perfectly valid `text/plain` data. That example *won't* work, because PHP will see that the data is marked as being `text/plain` and won't parse it into `$_POST`.